# css space out text in a row but keep in alignment with each other/keep left?

Tags: css, text

I have the following rows containing my mysql results like so:

```
<div class="request"><p><?php echo $row['data1']; ?></p><p><?php echo $row['data2']; ?></p><p><?php echo $row['data3']; ?></p><p><?php echo $row['data4']; ?></p></div>


<div class="request"><p><?php echo $row['data4']; ?></p><p><?php echo $row['data2']; ?></p><p><?php echo $row['data1']; ?></p><p><?php echo $row['data3']; ?></p></div>
```

This looks like so:

```
Bank Details            A/C: 1234567        S/C: 01-00-01     Tuesday 2nd Feb
Invoice Details            Ref: 12322323        Pending     Friday 12th Feb
```

my problem is that each row will contain different values each time like shown above. Some rows will display bank details, like account numbers and sort codes and others will contain invoice details like reference numbers and status.

The rows are displaying in a mistmatch sort of way where the text is all over the place. My question is how do I get the text to align to the left so it's nice and tidy like so:

```
Bank Details            A/C: 1234567        S/C: 01-00-01     Tuesday 2nd Feb
Invoice Details         Ref: 12322323       Pending           Friday 12th Feb
```

Heres my css:

```
.request{
    height:20px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    cursor:pointer;
    cursor:hand;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}

.request p{
text-align:left;
display:inline-block;
width:auto;
height:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
margin-right:17%;
float:left;
}
```

please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like tabular data so you should use a table like so:

```
<table cellspacing="16px">
    <tr>
        <td>Bank Details</td>
        <td>A/C: 1234567</td>
        <td>S/C: 01-00-01</td>
        <td>Tuesday 2nd Feb</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Invoice Details</td>
        <td>Ref: 12322323</td>
        <td>Pending</td>
        <td>Friday 12th Feb</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/13kz5sjq/

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but I thought using tables was bad practice?

Comment: @JamesDaley: no, for this dataset it's only one correct solution.

Comment: Only for layout. If you're displaying data in a table format you should be using a table

Comment: Yup, tabular data = tables.